# Adding active class to main page and sub pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the `active` class to my nav bar links. I managed to solve the problem on my main pages, but when I go to a sub page the main page doesn't work anymore.

The URLs on my site are like: `localhost/project/user/index` and `localhost/project/user/edit/1`

My code works for the first index pages, but not for sub pages
Here is the code:
EDIT: Managed to find solution with includes() function and giving a element classes. Would like to see better way to do this without having to specify for each  navigation link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href ;
    $('ul.menu a').filter(function() {
       if( url.includes('user')) {
           $('ul.menu a.user').addClass('active');
       } else if (url.includes('team')) {
           $('ul.menu a.team').addClass('active');
       }
    })
});
```

Html:

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link user" href="http://localhost/project/user/index">
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link team" href="http://localhost/project/team/index">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This will work only if your `hrefs` are absolute, since you're comparing them to the full, absolute URL found in `window.location`.

Comment: @Utkanos i am new to javascript so i dont really understand all of this. Can you please help with the code example?

Comment: See answer.....

Answer (score 1):

You don't post your HTML, so I'm guessing here. But this is probably because you're comparing absolute URLs (`window.location`) with relative `href`s.

Say your generated HTML looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <a href='some-page.html'>
    <!-- ... -->
</nav>
```

Your code is never going to consider that the link above is 'on' because your `filter` function is comparing the relative `some-page.html` with something like `http://localhost/project/some-page.html`. Those two strings don't match.

As I say, this is a hunch because you haven't posted your HTML, but that's probably what's up.

To resolve it you can do one of two things:

- Have your `filter` callback parse the absolute `window.location` URL into just the relative part, and compare *that* with your `href`
- Or, easier, store absolute, not relative, URLs in your `hrefs` so you're matching apples with apples, not apples with oranges.

Comment: I added html in question

Comment: Utankos has given you the answer here.Have you tried this or are you waiting for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: @DanDevine Yes i am trying to solve problem with their help, but still no luck

Comment: @iposave I suggest you update your code to show us what you have tried since.

Comment: @DanDevine I tried few stuff but no luck, I updated code and now class active is added for main pages, like http://localhost/project/user/index but, when i go to subpage : http://localhost/project/user/add , things dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at `window.location.pathname` or `window.location.href`and basing your logic around that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  $('ul.menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
  }).addClass('active');
});
```

You can read more about window.location here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i still find the same problem. Code works for index pages, but not for sub pages.

Answer (score 0):

like it said above you are trying to compare relative href with a full href, and that will return 0

try it like this instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this will containe https://stackoverflow.com/js
  var url = window.location.href ;
  $('ul.menu a').filter(function() {
    return url.indexOf(this.href) != -1; // Containe insted of ==
  }).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
color:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
<a href="/js">
Click here 
</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But, i cannot change href of a element, because it will break links. Is there a way to solve this problem using full urls?

Comment: You dont need to change anything, this should work anyway. think about it if 1.indexOf(1) is still true. so this will work anyway